# Нужны ли запятые в написании адреса?

Tags: пунктуация

В каких случаях ставится запятая в адресе?

1. Мой адрес: г.Луганск, ул.Оборонная, д. 22, кв.15
2. Я живу в г.Свердловске Свердловского района Луганской области.

Правильно или нет я привела примеры? И в чём суть правила?

Comment: Во втором примере сокращение "г." обязательно развернуть: в городе Свердловске. Не забывайте про пробелы.

Answer (score 4):

Всё правильно. В первом примере элементы формально выраженного адреса, в  русском языке приводимые в последовательности от общего к частному, грамматически взаимно не согласованы. Поэтому они перечисляются через запятую. Во втором примере элементы адреса, приводимые в неформальном порядке (от частного к общему), согласованы по падежам, которые указывают на входимость одного элемента адреса в другой, причём таким конкретным образом, что запятых не требуется. Возможна и смешанная форма приведения адреса в подобном повествовании, где для разделения некоторых элементов адреса потребуются запятые. Например, чтобы подчеркнуть наименование города, грамматически связав его со сказуемым и ещё с каким-нибудь нужным элементом (напр., с улицей), и при этом разгрузить предложение от множественных падежно связанных других элементов адреса, можно часть адреса формализовать, приведя её в скобках как несогласованное пояснение того, где находится город:

> Я живу на улице Свердлова в городе Свердловске (Луганская область,
>   Свердловский район).

Answer (score 0):

Примеры Вы привели правильно.

В первом случае запятые ставятся после каждого [элемента адреса](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) (грамота.ру упоминает, что пары дом-корпус и дом-строение пишутся иногда иначе - см. [288486](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=288486)).

Во втором случае запятые не нужны.

P. S. Обратите внимание: по правилам русского языка после точки, обозначающей сокращение слова, необходимо ставить пробел. Отделите пробелом сокращение "г." ("город") и "ул." ("улица") от слов, к которым они примыкают: г. Луганск, ул. Оборонная, д. 22, кв. 152.